# Put element under focus in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put element under `focus` just after `append` it, means something similar to :

```
$("id").append($("elementid")).focus();        // not working
```

Comment: Are you forgetting `#` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try trigger

```
$("#id").trigger('focus');
```

Comment: thats the thing which i was looking for, thanks and thanks to all others also

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are adding focus to `id` element, that's why it doesn't work.

Try this solution instead:

```
$("#elementid").appendTo("#id").focus();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wRSBY/

Comment: It also doesn't work because they've omitted the `#` from the ID selectors (which you've added in your answer, but not commented on), so it's looking for elements of type `id` (i.e. created with an `<id>` tag) rather than the element with that specific ID.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) needs a `#` before the id.

So

```
$("#id").append($("#elementid")).focus();
```

should work if you want to put focus on your `#id` DOM element, if you want to put focus on the `#elementid` DOM element, then you can use [VisioN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932977/221213).

Comment: You can pass a selector straight to `.append()`, there's no need to create another jQuery object using that selector. I know you're just copying the code from the question, but no reason not to point out when things are being done unnecessarily.

Comment: I think the OP wants to focus the appended element.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: the documentation does not list the selectors as accepted parameters here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @KARASZIIstván You're right. I guess I was confusing it with `.appendTo()`.